# wxpython Gridsizer not fitting to panel

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, panel, sizer

I am working on a wxpython GUI.  I have three panels (two on the left split horizontally and one on the right split vertically from the other two -- think two squares on left half and tall rectangle on right half).  I am trying to fit a Gridsizer in Panel 3 (P3 in image).  I cannot seem to get the grid panels to "fill" the overall Panel 3.  Instead they snap to the top and bottom.  Ideally, i would like the 10 small panels (2 rows, 5 cols) to resize and fill the Panel 3 nicely (all the same size and big enough to see each).  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

**** EDIT ****
I have changed my code to look like the following:

```
        sizer_31 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        gs = wx.GridSizer(0,4,7,7)

        for i in self.Panel_Others.keys():
            gs.Add(self.Panel_Others[i],0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL,5)

        sizer_31.Add(gs,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL,5)
        self.OtherTeams.SetSizer(sizer_31)
        sizer_31.SetSizeHints(self.OtherTeams)
```

And my New Panel 3 looks like the picture below.  This is some improvement.  However, I want the individual panels (10 in all) to expand the same amount so that the entire notebook page is covered in equal size smaller panels (Imagine what a Calendar looks like and each day is a panel).

[image]

**** END EDIT ****

Below is my original code:

Note:  `self.OtherTeams` is the wx.Notebook Page under `self.Panel3`. `self.Panel_Others` is a dictionary containing the wx.Panels I'm displaying (this changes dynamically so this is why i have a dictionary of them rather than specifying them).

```
        sizer_31 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        gs = wx.GridSizer(2,5,5,5)

        for i in self.Panel_Others.keys():
            sizer_temp = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer_temp.Add(self.Panel_Others[i],1,wx.EXPAND)
            gs.Add(sizer_temp,1,wx.EXPAND,0)

        sizer_31.Add(gs,0,wx.EXPAND)
        self.OtherTeams.SetSizer(sizer_31)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `wxPython 2.8` this would result in a single blur at the top left corner of the page.
`wxPython 2.9` is a bit smarter when it comes to sizers which is why it appears to work somewhat.

Firstly, you create a `GridSizer` within a `BoxSizer` but you do not allow it to expand dynamically (`wx.EXPAND`).
And secondly, you're setting the sizer to the `wx.Notebook` instead of the page (panel) which would shift the entire layout down and crop the bottom row of controls/panels in the grid sizer, or would be ignored entirely in `2.8` thus moving everything to the top left corner.

This should do the trick:

```
sizer_31 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # page (panel) sizer for outer border
gs = wx.GridSizer(0,4,7,7) # content sizer

for i in self.Panel_Others.keys():
    gs.Add(self.Panel_Others[i],0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,5) 
    # + wx.EXPAND: allow the content to fill the 'cells'
    #              (proportion is ignored here so it can be 0)
sizer_31.Add(gs,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,5) 
# + 1, wx.EXPAND: allow the grid to expand to the main sizer
#                 which in turn fits to the page
self.Panel3.SetSizer(sizer_31) # set the sizer to page, not the notebook
```

**EDIT**: The following example demonstrates how to dynamically update the contents of a wx.GridSizer in a wx.Notebook page:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='wx.Notebook')
        # create a wx.Notebook
        book = wx.Notebook(self)
        # create a new page; wx.Notebook owns the page
        # therefore the notebook must be the parent window
        page = MyPage(parent=book)
        # add the page to the notebook:
        book.AddPage(page, 'Page 1')
        book.AddPage(MyPage(book),'Page 2')
        book.AddPage(MyPage(book),'Page 3')

class MyPage(wx.Panel):
    "a page for wx.Notebook"
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # NOTE: wxPython 2.9.4/winXP may create graphic 
        # artifacts when more than one page is added. This can
        # be avoided by creating the page with a size of (0,0).
        # the reason for this is: the page (here a panel) is
        # created with the default size and position (upper
        # left corner). Once the layout is applied, the page
        # is moved to the proper coordinates. However, the
        # wx.Notebook is not redrawn so it will leave a black
        # spot where the page was moved away from. Alternatively,
        # the frame or notebook can be Refresh()ed after the
        # frame is shown.
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(0,0))
        # create sizer to add a border
        pageSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # create a grid sizer for the content
        self.grid = wx.GridSizer(0, 4, 5, 5)
        # add the grid sizer to the page sizer:
        # to allow the grid to fill the entire page,
        # set proportion>0 and add the wx.EXPAND flag.
        # the border of 10 is the spacing between the
        # page and the cells of the grid
        pageSizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        # set the main sizer:
        self.SetSizer(pageSizer)
        # add content to the grid
        self.GenerateContent()
        # DEMO: click any white space on the page to 
        # generate new content
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.GenerateContent)

    def GenerateContent(self, event=None):
        "dynamically create page content"
        # remove all items from the grid and destroy them
        # NOTE: if you don't actually create new controls here,
        # but use a list of controls created elsewhere (like in
        # in your code), do not delete the items! Use:
        # deleteWindows=False instead.
        self.grid.Clear(deleteWindows=True)
        # generate new grid content
        for i in range(10):
            # the contents are owned by the page,
            # therefore the page must be the parent window:
            # NOTE: size=(0,0) here is not required but
            # eliminates a briefly shown graphic artifact
            cell = wx.Panel(self, size=(0,0))
            cell.SetBackgroundColour(self.NewColor())
            # add the content (cells) to the grid:
            # specify the wx.EXPAND flag to fit the
            # content to the grid cell
            self.grid.Add(cell, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # DEMO: hint text
        self.grid.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label=
            'Click empty cell to update content ->'),
                      flag=wx.EXPAND)
        # recalculate the layout to move the new contents
        # of the grid sizer into place
        self.Layout()

    col = 0 # DEMO: coloring
    def NewColor(self):
        self.col = (self.col + 3) % 241
        return wx.Colour(0, self.col * 10 % 255, self.col % 255)

app = wx.App(False)
MyFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```